# io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED when querying Secret Manager from App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I'm trying to list secrets in Secret Manager with `listSecrets()` from an App Engine app, but the grpc requests keeps timing out after 60 s:

```
com.google.api.gax.rpc.DeadlineExceededException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded after 59.973305176s.
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:51)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)
        at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1074)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1213)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:983)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:771)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:563)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:533)
        at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$CloseListenerRunnable.runInContext(DelayedClientCall.java:406)
        at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
        Suppressed: com.google.api.gax.rpc.AsyncTaskException: Asynchronous task failed
```

I verified that I can use other GCP services from App Engine, and that my App Engine default service account has Secret Manager roles. My app is a second generation Java 11 app in the standard environment. I'm using v23.0.0 of `libraries-bom` (the latest). The same code works fine when I run it locally, and it shouldn't take more than a few seconds, so I'm wondering if it's an issue with the App Engine environment or its service account.

Update: I ended up using google-api-services-secretmanager/google-api-client/google-auth-library-oauth2-http. This snipped worked fine locally and on App Engine.

```
var projectId = "<TODO>";
var credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();
var secretManager = new SecretManager.Builder(
        new NetHttpTransport(),
        new GsonFactory(),
        new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials))
        .build();

ArrayList<Secret> secrets = new ArrayList<>();
String pageToken = null;
do {
    var response = secretManager.projects().secrets().list("projects/" + projectId)
            .setPageToken(pageToken)
            .execute();
    pageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
    secrets.addAll(response.getSecrets());
} while (pageToken != null);
```

Comment: can you check this link: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/4220 is it helpful?

Comment: Do any other google APIs work from App Engine?

Comment: @SandroB I was able to use Bigquery.

Comment: @DivyaniYadav I saw that when I googled my issue. I don't think that's my problem because it's timing out when reading from an empty Pubsub queue, and timing out is reasonable. I'm seeing a timeout on a `listSecrets()` call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally looked at the logs (not just the exception) and saw this

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find policy 'pick_first'. Make sure its implementation is either registered to LoadBalancerRegistry or included in META-INF/services/io.grpc.LoadBalancerProvider from your jar files.
    at io.grpc.internal.AutoConfiguredLoadBalancerFactory$AutoConfiguredLoadBalancer.<init>(AutoConfiguredLoadBalancerFactory.java:92)
    at io.grpc.internal.AutoConfiguredLoadBalancerFactory.newLoadBalancer(AutoConfiguredLoadBalancerFactory.java:63)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.exitIdleMode(ManagedChannelImpl.java:406)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$RealChannel$2.run(ManagedChannelImpl.java:978)
    at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.drain(SynchronizationContext.java:95)
    at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.execute(SynchronizationContext.java:127)
    ...
```

Which led to [a Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55484043/how-to-fix-could-not-find-policy-pick-first-with-google-tts-java-client) and a [Github issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/5493#issuecomment-478500418).

My build uses the Maven Shade plugin. Two artifacts, `io.grpc:grpc-grpclb`, and `io.grpc:grpc-core` have a `META-INF/services/io.grpc.LoadBalancerProvider` file, but the `grpc-core` is the one I want. Adding an exclusion to my shade config fixed it:

```
<filter>
    <artifact>io.grpc:grpc-grpclb</artifact>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>META-INF/services/io.grpc.LoadBalancerProvider</exclude>
    </excludes>
</filter>
```

Comment: did it solve your issue?

Comment: Yes; "adding an exclusion to my shade config fixed it"